# how to calculate the coordinates of the free space on the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to post notification forms but I do not want the forms to overlap. How do I determine the free space on the screen to display the lab form?

Sorry for the bad english!

Comment: The code will not know what "free space" means, you'll have to keep track of the form(s) currently on screen and their positions in the code by yourself, and then add a new one after comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get screen size for primary screen like this:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle workingRectangle = 
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.
For multi-monitor configurations you can enumerate screens using `Screen.AllScreens`

After you have screen space you can find out free space for each side of your form:

```
int availableSpaceOnLeft = yourForm.Left - workingRectangle.Left;
int availableSpaceOnTop = yourForm.Top- workingRectangle.Top;
int availableSpaceOnRight = workingRectangle.Right - yourForm.Right;
int availableSpaceOnBottom = workingRectangle.Bottom - yourForm.Bottom;
```